# Gamecube is in black and white on HDTV

Tags: nintendo-gamecube

I tried to plug my GameCube into my HDTV, but it displays in black and white. I could still play and hear everything. I have all the original cables for my GameCube, and it only does it with the Vizio TV I have. How do I fix this?

Answer (score -2):

Since it's only on your Vizio TV then it probably means that you need to change some setting on your TV. On my Vizio you have to open the menu, go to picture, and then make sure your Color field is set to something around 50. If the color is set to 0 it will be displayed in black and white.

You might also want to try out the other inputs on your TV if there are any more that work for it.

If that didn't fix it then it could be the TV.